# React functional bases props is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props, react-functional-component

i need your helps.

I have a functional based component call WelcomeSlidePage. I want to pass a functional to the functional component. i try to console.log the function in functional component, in the first state, console.log is printing the function, but after the second state, it's becomes undefine.

this is my component that calling the functional component

> WebViewPage.jsx

```
<Modal transparent={true} visible={this.state.WelcomeSlidePageModal} animationType="     
    <WelcomeSlidePage onDone={()=>{console.log('test bro');this.setState({WelcomeSlidePageModal:false})}}/>
</Modal>
```

and this is my functional component

> WelcomeSlidePage.jsx

```
  import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
  import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
  import AppIntroSlider from 'react-native-app-intro-slider';
  import string from '../string'
  import { _storeData, _getData } from '../components/StoreAsync';

  export default WelcomeSlide = (props) => {
    const [language, setLanguage] =       useState('english');
    const [showRealApp, setShowRealApp] = useState(false);
    const welcomeSlide = string.welcome_slide[language]

    useEffect(() => { 
      console.log('testing bro',props.onDone)
      // getData();
    });
    async function getData() {
      setLanguage(    await _getData("language"));
      setShowRealApp( await _getData("showRealApp"));
    }

    _renderItem = ({ item }) => {
      switch (item.key) {
        case ('k4'):
          return (
            <View style={{backgroundColor : '#a0c83a', flex: 1}}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
              <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', paddingHorizontal: 20, flex: 1}}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{item.text_4_a}</Text>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                  <Image style={styles.icon} source={item.icon} />
                  <Text style={{paddingStart: 5, paddingEnd: 20, ...styles.text}}>{item.text_4_b}</Text>
                </View>

                <Text style={styles.text}>{item.text_4_c}</Text>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                  <Image style={styles.icon} source={item.icon} />
                  <Text style={{paddingStart: 5, paddingEnd: 20, ...styles.text}}>{item.text_4_d}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
            );
        case ('k5'):
            return (
              <View style={styles.slide}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{item.text_5}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{marginVertical: 24}} onPress={()=>{ props.navigation.navigate('WebView', { url: string.onboarding[language].login_url }); }}>
                  <Text style={styles.button}>{item.text_5_btn1}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{marginVertical: 24}} onPress={()=>{ props.navigation.navigate('WebView', { url: string.onboarding[language].register_url }); }}>
                  <Text style={styles.button}>{item.text_5_btn2}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            );
        default:
          return (
            <View style={styles.slide}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
              <Image style={styles.image} source={item.image} />
              <Text style={{paddingHorizontal: 20, ...styles.text}}>{item.text}</Text>
            </View>
          );
      }
    }

    _onDone = () => {
      setShowRealApp(true);

      _storeData('isPassSlide',true);
      props.navigation.navigate('WebView', { url: string.onboarding[language].login_url,splashScreen:false });
    }

    const slides = [
      {
        key:    'k1',
        title:  welcomeSlide.title,
        text:   welcomeSlide.a,
        image:  require('../images/my_library_card_white_notext_nopadding.png'),
        backgroundColor: '#a0c83a',
      },
      {
        key:    'k2',
        title:  welcomeSlide.title,
        text:   welcomeSlide.b,
        image:  require('../images/my_account_white_notext_nopadding.png'),
        backgroundColor: '#a0c83a',
      },
      {
        key:    'k3',
        title:  welcomeSlide.title,
        text:   welcomeSlide.c,
        image:  require('../images/library_catalog_white_notext_nopadding.png'),
        backgroundColor:'#a0c83a',
      },
      {
        key:      'k4',
        title:    welcomeSlide.title,
        text_4_a: welcomeSlide.d_a,
        text_4_b: welcomeSlide.d_b,
        text_4_c: welcomeSlide.d_c,
        text_4_d: welcomeSlide.d_d,
        icon:     require('../images/icon-hand-right.png'),
        backgroundColor: '#a0c83a',
      },
      {
        key:         'k5',
        text_5:      welcomeSlide.e,
        text_5_btn1: welcomeSlide.e_btn1,
        text_5_btn2: welcomeSlide.e_btn2,
        backgroundColor:'#a0c83a',
      },
    ];

    return(
      <AppIntroSlider
        renderItem={_renderItem}
        prevLabel={string.back[language]}
        nextLabel={string.next[language]}
        doneLabel={string.next[language]}
        showPrevButton={true}
        slides={slides}
        onDone={()=>props.onDone()}/>
    )
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    slide : {
      flex: 1,
      paddingTop: (Platform.OS) === 'ios' ? 20 : 0,
      paddingBottom: 80,
      backgroundColor : '#a0c83a',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    title: {
      fontSize: 24,
      color: '#fff',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      textAlign: 'center',
      marginTop : 30,
    },
    text: {
      fontSize : 20,
      color: '#fff',
      textAlign: 'left',
    },
    image: {
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      resizeMode: 'contain',
      flex:1,
    },
    icon: {
      top: 10,
      width: 25,
      height: 15,
      width: 25,
      marginTop: -3,
    },
    content: {
      paddingHorizontal: 20,
    },
    button: {
      borderRadius: 8,
      paddingVertical: 12,
      paddingHorizontal: 12,
      color: 'white',
      fontSize: 24,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      textAlign: 'center',
      marginHorizontal: 40,
      backgroundColor: '#e46825',
      shadowColor: '#000',
      shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
      shadowOpacity: 0.8,
      shadowRadius: 2,
      elevation: 5,
    },
  });
```

and then this is the console log

```
testing bro function onDone() {
            console.log('test bro');

            _this2.setState({
              WelcomeSlidePageModal: false
            });
          } b11b05fa-4e76-41da-9d58-218edc178e45:157683:15
testing bro undefined
```

please help me guys, thanks

Comment: Could you show full code of `WelcomeSlide`?

Comment: I have edited it so that it shows the entire code of ```WelcomeSlide```

Comment: I think `onDone` can't be `undefined` there. You could try to log entire `props` to check. Beside, I am not sure what you are trying to archive but if you implement `useEffect` without dependency like that, it will be triggered every render.

Comment: i've tried to console log outside the useEffect but its still give me same result

Comment: it is effect if the parent component is class based component ?

Comment: No, it is not a problem